# Bypass layout for a component in Swing without null layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

Is there a way to bypass the layout manager for a given component in Swing? Something similar to position="absolute" in CSS. Null layout is not an option.

I have an existing GUI which I **can't modify** and uses different kinds of layouts and I need to add a button a the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: there are three [LayoutManagers can do that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), two without special effort

Comment: I know how to use Layout Managers. Please check my edit.

Comment: Can you add/append a menu/item & `Action`?

Comment: No, it is a fullscreen app. A JTabbedPane is the main container (child of a JFrame) and it fits all the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the existing GUI, including the top-level containing `JFrame`, you might be out of luck.

If you can modify the root container, you can achieve what you want with a [layered pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).  You can put your existing `JTabbedPane` in a lower layer, and add your button on a higher layer (and there you *can* use a `null` layout + `setLocation()`).